# Is there a way to search by clan tag on Battlelog?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way on battlelog (or somewhere else) to search players by clan tag? I've looked through battlelog and googled and haven't found anything.

We run a clan at work and I'd just like to see who else has added our tag to their username so far, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. You'd think viewing all the players attached to a certain clan tag would be an obviously useful view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no means via Battlelog to search for which users applied a Clan-tag to their name.  **Anyone can have their own custom clan / platoon name adhered to their Origin username (but in Battlelog's eyes: they will not be representing any real platoon, unless...-see below).**

If you are looking for users who strictly are 'representing' a specific clan, that clan needs to be a platoon and those users need to be a part of that platoon.  If this is true, search by the platoon name under the platoon menu - click on *Find or Create new Platoon*.

Once you find the platoon desired, look at their roster to see who *represents* that platoon.